# I've set a value on a class property on Form1, but when I tried to access it on Form2 it doesn't return a value, why?

Tags: c#, class, properties

```
class User
{
    public string set_name;

    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.set_name;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.set_name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Form1

```
User id = new User();
id.name = textbox1.Text;
```

Form2

```
User _name = new User();
label1.Text = _name.name;
```

Comment: `new` means the same in programming as everyday life

Comment: You are creating a new, separate instance of `User`, it has nothing to do with the `User` instance you have used previously(apart from the same class name).

Comment: Ahh, then I can't access the value I set on form1?

Comment: @VnzDichoso: If `Form1` opens `Form2`, `Form1` is the controller of `Form2` and should pass all necessary informations, for example via constructor in `Form2` or via public property.

Answer (score 3):

I have a piece of paper, and I write my name on it. If I then get a *completely different*  piece of paper, my name is not automatically on it. It is the same here - there are two `User` objects here, completely unrelated. If you want the `name` from the first, you need to *pass that `User` object* to the second form.

Comment: I there another way that I could save the value and access it through different forms without passing it?

Comment: @VnzDichoso you can pass the *name* (just the value, the string), or you can pass the entire `User` object and everything it contains along with it. There *is* a third way, but it is a bad option and inappropriate to use here. So I'm not even going to mention it, other to acknowledge that it exists. Rajeev has done that for me ;p

Comment: A piece of paper can be used for everything, not only for usernames. Perhaps: i have a baby, i name it Jon, now all people have the name Jon, better?

Answer (score 1):

You can create class as static

```
static class User
{        
    public string set_name;

    public static string name
    {
      get
      {
        return this.set_name;
      }
      set 
      {
        this.set_name = value;
      }
}
```

and get and set like this

```
User.name = textbox1.Text; // Form1

label1.Text = User.name; // Form2
```

Comment: Bad idea imo, should pass the user object

Comment: The number of occasions where this type of static state is appropriate is *vanishingly* small, and frankly I don't think that small set includes this usage.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes i totally agree with you :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I have just provide the alternative. passing the object to constructor is another solution for OP